# sshuttle analog for mac

Tags: macos, ssh-tunnel, sshuttle

We have tried using latest sshuttle on Mac OS X Mountain Lion, but there is a bug which messes with kernel variables and by this breaks internet connection. On the machine where we tried it we had to reinstall system since issue did not seem to be fixable. However we perfectly use it on Linux.

So I wonder if there is any analog of sshuttle for Mac that will allow us pipe `all` connections through SSH tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this SU answered question](https://superuser.com/questions/468919/prevent-outgoing-traffic-unless-openvpn-connection-is-active-using-pf-conf-on-ma) to be relevant; I was unaware that mDNSresponder was how the OS determined the state of the wireless connection..

Also, I haven't used it personally, you might wish to evaluate [MacProxy](http://www.tidalpool.ca/macproxy/):

> **Features:**
>
> redirect your Mac's network traffic to any compatible SOCKS or HTTP proxy server
>
> works with browsers (Safari, Firefox), email (Mail), chat (iChat, Skype), FTP, telnet, and many more network applications
>
> enable and switch the active proxy conveniently from a menulet
>
> track session statistics including the number of active connections and data sent/received
>
> DNS resolution through the proxy server
>
> secure browsing by hiding your IP address
>
> support for SOCKS proxy protocols including versions 4, 4a, and 5
>
> support for HTTP/web proxy protocols including transparent, non-transparent, and connect
>
> SSH tunnel support - connect securely to a remote Mac to prevent snooping over WiFi networks
>
> rules - proxy or ignore connections based on IP addresses, ports, domains (with wildcard support), and applications
>
> quickly determine which proxy protocol a server supports using the built-in proxy checker
>
> anonymize requests option (HTTP non-transparent only)
>
> multiple user support - works for all users on a Mac
>
> 32/64-bit universal preference pane, application, and kernel extension
>
> logging support
>
> **What's new in MacProxy 2.0.4 (history):**
> Mac OS X Mountain Lion (10.8) compatibility

Comment: This doesn't work for all connections. Only for certain applications that have proxy option builtin. In my question I mentioned that I need to pipe all the connections through ssh tunnel the same way as sshuttle does.